# When is a Dedekind group abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

A Dedekind group is a group all of whose subgroups are normal (see [Dedekind group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_group) for more information).

My question is: given that a group is Dedekind, what further conditions tell us that it is abelian (besides the obvious, such as 'all elements commute')?

Dedekind groups are completely classified: they are either of the form $G=Q_8 \oplus B \oplus D$, where $Q_8$ is the quaternion group, $B$ is an elementary abelian 2-group, and $D$ is a periodic abelian group all of whose elements have odd order, OR they are abelian.  So to show that a Dedekind group is not abelian we can show that it contains a subgroup isomorphic to $Q_8$.  I don't see a good way to do this though.  If we look for non-commuting elements, this doesn't take advantage of the Dedekind-ness, and outside of this I don't see any way to distinguish a Hamiltonian group from an abelian Dedekind group.

Thanks.

Comment: Non-abelian Dedekind groups( Hamiltonian group) have the form $Q_8 \times B \times D$, not the abelian ones.

Comment: @Deiborlang: Yes, that was in there originally and didn't make it back in when I had to edit.  As I said though, I don't see a way to show that G contains a subgroup isomorphic to $Q_8$ other than just finding non-commuting elements, which isn't any different than most cases where we're trying to show that a group is abelian or not.

Comment: See the theorem $5.3.7$ of the [book](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=lqyCjUFY6WAC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) on page $143$.