# To derive commutativeness of any group from the normality of all its subgroups & some other conditions

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, normal-subgroups

If a group is abelian then it is known that every subgroup of the group is normal ; is the converse true i.e. if every subgroup of a group is normal , then is it true that the grroup is   abelian ? If this converse is not true , then is their a partial converse  ?

Comment: The converse is not true. See, e. g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_group).

Comment: @martini:- and what about some partial converse ? can some extra restrictions be added to make the group abelian  ?

Comment: See the link @martini gave you.  It's true if the group contains no copy of the quaternion group, for example.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551000/when-is-a-dedekind-group-abelian.